# C++ - std::set constructor sometimes very inefficient?

Tags: c++

I am trying to construct a set in the following manner:

```
    std::set<SomeType> mySet(aVector.begin(), aVector.end());
```

The performance of this line is very efficient in most cases. 10% of the time, I run into cases where this takes too long to run (over 600 milliseconds in some cases!). Why could that be happening? The inputs are very similar each time (the vector is for the most part sorted). Any ideas?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a way to reproduce the slowness (e.g. by providing the data, or a way to generate the data) along with some timings and some basic details of your platform/compiler.

Comment: At least post few input vectors which you use in the constructor. Why do you want us to speculate without giving us more information about the input?

Comment: Set is a ordered container. If your vector is already sorted you will get linear time in the construction. If your vector is not sorted you will get N*log(N).

Comment: A random 600 msec slowdown feels like a page fault or several task switches. How much data are you handling? Is the system under memory pressure? Are there other processes contending the CPU? How are you measuring these times?

Comment: Why would the page fault or context switching happen only within this set construction code? When I run metrics on other areas of the code, I never see the 600 msec spike.

Comment: What is the size of the vector/set? How expensive is the comparison operator used by the set?

Comment: 600msec might be nothing or an eternity... how are you actually measuring performance?

Comment: user763305, the vector contains around 2000 elements. Each element is a struct that contains 15 or so double members. The key comparison used is simply comparing one double with another.

Comment: David Rodríguez - dribeas, I am using QueryPerformanceCounter.

Comment: As others said, things could depend on the implementation, so the platform. I had a quick look at the set class provided with vs2008 and the constructor that you are using actually calls an 'insert' on the set for each element included between iter:begin and iter:end. The result of this could be a lot of memory allocation going on, so the 600ms might not be so unrealistic. Also, your elements are not very small objects, which usually means copying data around, probably with a memcpy under the hood, cache misses, etc... hope this helps.

Comment: One thing that I'm always suspicious of when dealing with std::set or std::map problems is the implementation of the comparison operator you're using.  In your example, you're relying on `SomeType`'s `operator<` to perform the comparison.  If that operator isn't written in a way that makes your `SomeType`s a [strict partial ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set), then you will run into weirdness.

Comment: Upvoted superbatfish's comment and updated my answer. In particular that you said you're using doubles could mean NaN is the culprit.

Answer (score 4):

I see three likely possibilities:

1. `operator<` for your structs isn't implementing a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering), which is required for std::set to work correctly. Keep in mind if your double values are ever `NaN`, you are breaking this assumption (on one of the sets that took a long time look to see if there are NaNs).
2. Occasionally your data isn't very sorted. Try always doing a std::sort on the vector first and see if the performance flattens out -- default construct the set then use the std::set::insert that takes two parameters, the first being a hint for what element to compare against first (if you can provide a good hint). That will let you build the set without resorting. If that fixes the spikes you know the initial sortedness of the data is the cause.
3. Your heap allocator occasionally does an operation that makes it take much longer than normal. It may be splitting or joining blocks to find free memory on the particular std::set() calls that are taking longer. You can try using an alternative allocator (if your program is multithreaded you might try [Google's tcmalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html)). You can rule this out if you have a profiler that shows time spent in the allocator, but most lack this feature. Another alternative would be [to use a boost::intrusive_set](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/intrusive/set_multiset.html), which will prevent the need for allocation when storing the items in the set.

Comment: a sorted vector would make this even slower, what chances has this constructor but just inserting one element after another, which means by having the list sorted it will run on worse time, the tree behind the set have to be balanced the maximum of possibilities, unsorted or even randomized would be much better

Comment: @ConfusedSushi: You're right that the performance would be worse, but if either sorting or randomizing makes the spike go away then you know  where the problem is. If you know the vector is sorted you can loop through it doing the two parameter std::set::insert where you provide a hint to do the initial construction. I'd prefer that to introducing nondeterminism :) ... updated answer.